# why did I get an Error saying the service I created with ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just computed this piece of code :

[Service + controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppg4K.png)

[image]

And I got this error once compiled on the browser:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl67e.png)

[image]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legacy methods provided by **$http** are deprecated.

You have to use **.then()** reference to work with the response.

Read about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Your code could be like,

```
serviceAjax.popular($scope.currentPage)
   .then(function successCallback(response) {
     // this callback will be called asynchronously
     // when the response is available
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
     // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
 });
```

Comment: Thank you Sudhansu Choudhary. Completely solved the problem.